# Only allow merge request from dev branch to master branch and disallow other branch to merge directly to master branch in Gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am thinking of a setup where there will be three types of branches.

These are the following:

- master = which is the master/release
- dev = which where all the development goes to and get merge to be ready for release
- feature = which are branches where features are in development. These branches will be merge to dev branch in preparation for release.

I would like to make a rule where, these feature branches would not be able to create merge request directly to the master branch. If a feature needs to be deployed to production, it must first be merge to dev and then make a merge request from dev to master.

I am using Gitlab for CI/CD. Is it possible to create this rule where feature branches can only make merge request to dev and only dev branch can make merge request to master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect your branches so that e.g. only `maintainers` (or individual accounts) are allowed to merge into `master`. See [GitLab CE - Protected Branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html).

You can also disallow direct pushes into `master`, `dev` or whatever branch you want to protect.

A general rule to disallow merging from an explicit branch to another is AFAIK not possible.

Comment: It is confirmed then. Thanks!